# Is there a syntax checker for cron.d files?

Tags: cron

Is there a lint tool or a command line syntax checker for the files in `/etc/cron.d`? I work on a support team, and some members of the team have been known to mix up the syntax for `crontab` and `/etc/cron.d` (i.e. omitting the user), and since such entries will cause all of the entries in the file to fail, I would like to be able to test the entries in a given file in `/etc/cron.d` to make sure that the syntax is correct before cron jobs start failing.

I've read through the `cron(8)` man page and searched google and serverfault for `cron.d lint` and `cron.d syntax checker` with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this can help you: [chkcrontab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chkcrontab) In short:

> chkcrontab is a script to check crontab files like those in
>   /etc/cron.d and /etc/crontab. It tries to catch glaring errors and
>   warn on suspect lines in a crontab file. Some valid lines will
>   generate warnings. Certain silly yet valid crontab lines will generate
>   errors as well.

Alternatively,  you can routinely check for `cron` logs (especially for the string "bad minute")

Comment: Yeah, I found `chkcrontab` shortly after I posted. (note to self -- google for 'cron syntax checker' not 'cron.d syntax checker'). It looks like a good tool.